# Google V3 Add click Listner

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I am new to JavaScript,  i want to migrate from Google V2 to Google v3, for this i am just changing methods which are used in V2 slightly all are working but when i am trying to change the `addListener` from V2 to V3 i am facing problems like in v2 same listener is used to put the marker on the map but when it comes to V3 i am not able to put a marker on the map.Here i am posting v2 code and V3 code.Please help me to over come the problem. V2 is :

```
GEvent.addListener(map, "click", function(marker, point) {
                console.debug('after Click map is '+map+' marker is '+marker+' point is '+point);
                if (marker) {
                        if(PolygonMarkers.length == 1){ //Only one marker in the array
                            map.removeOverlay(PolygonMarkers[0]);
                            map.removeOverlay(PolygonMarkers[0]);
                            PolygonMarkers = [];
                            if(Polygon){map.removeOverlay(Polygon)};
                        } else{                     /*More then one marker*/
                            var RemoveIndex = -1;
                            var Remove;
                            //Search for clicked Marker in PolygonMarkers Array
                            for(var m=0; m<PolygonMarkers.length; m++)
                            {
                                if(PolygonMarkers[m].getPoint().equals(marker.getPoint()))
                                {
                                    RemoveIndex = m; Remove = PolygonMarkers[m];
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                            //Shift Array elements to left
                            for(var n=RemoveIndex; n<PolygonMarkers.length-1; n++)
                            {
                                PolygonMarkers[n] = PolygonMarkers[n+1];
                            }
                            PolygonMarkers.length = PolygonMarkers.length-1 //Decrease Array length by 1
                            map.removeOverlay(Remove); //Remove Marker
                            geofencedetails.drawPolygon(); //Redraw Polygon
                          }  

                        allMarkers = PolygonMarkers;

                  } else {
                    // Adds a new Polygon boundary marker 
                        var markerOptions = { icon: icon, draggable: true };
                        var marker = new GMarker(point, markerOptions);
                        PolygonMarkers.push(marker); //Add marker to PolygonMarkers array
                        map.addOverlay(marker); //Add marker on the map
                        GEvent.addListener(marker,'dragstart',function(){ //Add drag start event
                            marker.setImage(icon.image);
                            polygon_resizing = true;
                        });
                        GEvent.addListener(marker,'drag',function(){ 
                            geofencedetails.drawPolygon(); 
                            }); //Add drag event
                        GEvent.addListener(marker,'dragend',function(){   //Add drag end event
                            marker.setImage(icon.image);
                            polygon_resizing = false;
                            geofencedetails.drawPolygon();
                        });
                        geofencedetails.drawPolygon();

                        allMarkers = PolygonMarkers;
                 }
                });`
```

and V3 is

```
        google.maps.event.addListener(map, "click", function(marker, point) {
            if (marker) {
                //console.debug('marker '+marker.toSource());
                if(PolygonMarkers.length == 1){ //Only one marker in the array
                    map.removeOverlay(PolygonMarkers[0]);
                map.removeOverlay(PolygonMarkers[0]);
                PolygonMarkers = [];
                if(Polygon){
                    map.removeOverlay(Polygon)
                };
                }else {                     /*More then one marker*/
                    //console.debug('PolygonMarkers.length is '+PolygonMarkers.length);
                    var RemoveIndex = -1;
                    var Remove;
                    //Search for clicked Marker in PolygonMarkers Array
                    for(var m=0; m<PolygonMarkers.length; m++){
                        //console.debug('PolygonMarkers['+m+'] '+PolygonMarkers[m]);
                        if(PolygonMarkers[m].getPosition().equals(marker.getPosition())){
                            //console.debug('Both are equal ');
                            RemoveIndex = m;
                            Remove = PolygonMarkers[m];
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    //Shift Array elements to left
                    for(var n=RemoveIndex; n<PolygonMarkers.length-1; n++){
                        PolygonMarkers[n] = PolygonMarkers[n+1];
                    }
                    PolygonMarkers.length = PolygonMarkers.length-1 //Decrease Array length by 1
                    /*map.removeOverlay(Remove); //Remove Marker*/
                    for (var i = 0; i < allMarkers.length; i++ ) {
                        allMarkers[i].setMap(null);
                    }
                    geofencedetails.drawPolygon(); //Redraw Polygon
                }  

                allMarkers = PolygonMarkers;

            } else {
                //console.debug('In else block');
                // Adds a new Polygon boundary marker 
                var markerOptions = { icon: icon, draggable: true };
                //console.debug('1');
                var marker = new GMarker(point, markerOptions);
                //console.debug('2');
                PolygonMarkers.push(marker); //Add marker to PolygonMarkers array
                //console.debug('3');
                map.addOverlay(marker); //Add marker on the map
                //console.debug('4');
                GEvent.addListener(marker,'dragstart',function(){ //Add drag start event
                    //console.debug('5');
                marker.setImage(icon.image);
                //console.debug('6');
                polygon_resizing = true;
                });
                GEvent.addListener(marker,'drag',function(){ 
                    geofencedetails.drawPolygon(); 
                }); //Add drag event
                GEvent.addListener(marker,'dragend',function(){   //Add drag end event
                    marker.setImage(icon.image);
                polygon_resizing = false;
                geofencedetails.drawPolygon();
                });
                geofencedetails.drawPolygon();

                allMarkers = PolygonMarkers;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to bind the click event to the marker instead of the map.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function(event) { .... } );
```

> UI events within the Google Maps API V3 typically pass an event
>   argument, which can be accessed by the event listener, noting the UI
>   state when the event occurred. For example, a UI 'click' event
>   typically passes a MouseEvent containing a latLng property denoting
>   the clicked location on the map. Note that this behavior is unique to
>   UI events; MVC state changes do not pass arguments in their events.

Comment: Here marker is null,when i follow ur suggestion nothing is happen even iclick on the map and and BTW first time it should be null then it goes to 3rd else block and marker will  add to the map as per API-V2.I need to use the same code and need to just modify the existing code only.

Comment: It doesn't work that way in v3. It sounds like you need two different things. 1) When the map is clicked, a marker is added. 2) If that marker is then clicked, do something. You will need two listeners, one on the map to process the click and add the marker and then a listener on that marker instance to do something else.